# logstash is throwing exception template file not found

Tags: docker-compose, logstash, centos7, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to install docker-elk stack using docker-compose, elastic search and kibana are working fine, but my logstash is not connecting to elastic search and throwing error shown below, I'm installing this for first time so doesn't have much knowledge about it.

```
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,455][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Template file '' could not be found!", :class=>"ArgumentError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:37:in `read_template_file'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:23:in `get_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:7:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:58:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:25:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:9:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:43:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:310:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:235:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:398:in `start_pipeline'"]}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,455][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch-5-6:9201"]}
```

Logstash.conf

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5001
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9201"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the logstash pipeline cfg ( filter and output ) along with the question

Comment: @Ram ok sure I will edit the post and will add those

Comment: @Ram I have added configuration can you check it

Comment: The logstash on startup will try to install a default index template if none is present, The Index template will be available in the path ( if your logstah is installed in /opt ) Then the path will be /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-x.x-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/

check for the file elasticsearch-template-esXx.json ( where X is the elasticsearch version) is present, if not the logstash is not installed properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

providing the custom template and updating its path in output plugin solved the issue.